# How will water move across a membrane that is permeable to only one solute?

Tags: osmosis

If there are two solutions separated by a membrane, which is permeable only to one solute and the solvent, will there be any net movement? Let's assume the two solutes are glucose and sodium ions, with the same molarity, and only the glucose and water can pass through the membrane.

Comment: Is the membrane also permeable to the solvent? (water?)

Comment: Brownian motion describes there will be some movement. As glucose moves across the membrane, water will follow. I don't understand the nature of this question. Could you clarify? At the moment I think it's more suitable for chemistry.

Comment: Let's say the membrane is also permeable to water. James, I am interested if there will be any osmosis, also will there be any diffusion?

Comment: There will be net movement of glucose from high concentration to low concentration via diffusion, but not Na (as it cannot pass through).

Comment: @another'Homosapien' Let's say that's true. On one side, presumably there will be 1M of Na+ ions, and 0.5M glucose, then on the other side there is 0.5M glucose. If the solutions are in a U-tube, will there be differences in height of solution? Will there be anymore osmosis movement due to the differences in molarity (1.5 to 0.5 total solutes)?

Comment: There will be movement, but no net movement as water will keep moving from one side to another. When the side with Na+ becomes more concentrated, water will move that side which will increase concentration in the side not having Na+ by which water will then move that side. Thus there will be no net movement of water.

Comment: I am not exactly sure, so I would approach this question mathematically. And there is no point in differentiating osmosis from diffusion since osmosis can be thought of as diffusion of the solvent.

Comment: Ya so lets consider it mathematically. Lets assume a beaker of base 10cm x 20cm, of any height. Add 2 litres of water to it, it would come to a height of 10cm. Dividing the beaker equally into two with the semipermeable membrane of your specifications, we'll be left with 1 litre on each side. Now add 1 osmole glucose on one side and 1 osmole NaCl on the other (you can't add *only* Na+ ions). So now we have the setup, we sit back and watch what happens.

Comment: Since we have to predict whats going to happen and we are not able to, I guess it'll be safe to assume that $\ x $ moles of glucose moves to the other side resulting in a change in concentration on both sides. It should be kept in mind that osmosis and diffusion oren't mutually exclusive. Both will happen. As I said, osmosis is just the diffusion of the liquid. So water also move causing not only a change in concentration due to the change in volume distribution but also a change in *hydrostatic pressure*, a concern that you have pointed out.

Comment: Let the change in height be $\ y $ cm. Now the only constraint I can think of is that the pressure should be equal at the base. By pressure i mean the sum of both *hydrostatic and oncotic pressure*. Oncotic pressure is given by $\ P_o = icRT$ and hydrostatic is by $\ P_h = h\rho g$. 

Now I write $\ P_{o1} + P_{h1} = P_{o2} + P_{h2} $

That'd give $\ (h+y)\rho g + \frac{n+x}{(h+y)A}RT = (h-y)\rho g + \frac{n-x}{(h-y)A}RT$ 

Where $\ h$ is the height 10cm , $\ n$ is the no. of moles which we fixed as 1 mole (or rather, osmole)

Comment: So rest all are constants and the only variables left here is $\ y $ and  $\ x $ which we need.
 On solving, the equation comes to a cubic in $\ y$ which is actually not so desirable!! So I showed all this since this is the way I would proceed. But I am now struck, so I too want help from here on!! I guess it'd be better posting this on a chemistry forum.